# What should I do between 2 Forms?

Tags: c#

If I press Button1, the textBox1 in Form 2 ->  'Hello'

If I press button2 to show the form2 again, the word 'Hello' disappears and the text of the original Textbox1 will come out.

How do I keep the results that I press button1 from disappearing?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } 

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.textBox1.Text = "Hello";
        frm2.Show();
    } 

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

    public Form2(Form1 _form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm1 = _form;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: It disappears, because you create a new `Form2` in `Button2`. Declare `frm2` as class field in `Form1` instead and do not create a new one in `Button2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating instance of Form2 outside of button click events.

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm2.textBox1.Text = "Hello";
    frm2.Show();
} 

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand. But I don't know where I create an instance of Form2.

Comment: "Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);" this is the line where you are creating an instance of Form2, move this line to out side of click events and give a try.

Comment: hank you for your kindness. When I debug this code, it has System.StackOverflowException.     I think "Form1 frm1 = new Form1();" in Form2 is problem

Comment: @황준석: Yes, If `Form1` creates a `Form2` and `Form2` creates a `Form1`, then this new `Form1` creates again a `Form2` and this one again a `Form1` and so on..... In `Form2`, replace `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` by `Form1 frm1;`. since you assign it in the constructor, you don't need this `new Form1()` anyway.

Comment: following this code, it has an error like Form2 is deleted Objects

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the text that you set previously in `Form2`, then you are not allowed to close `Form2`. To prevent `Form2` from closing, set `e.Cancel = true;` in the `FormClosing` event handler:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; // Clancel closing
        Visible = false; // Instead, make Form2 invisible.
    }
}
```

Make sure to create the event handler in the form designer. Copy/paste alone will not wire up the event.

Code for `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _frm2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frm2.textBox1.Text = "Hello";
        _frm2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

---

But probably we look at it the wrong way. We should not use text boxes to store data. Instead, we create a data class for this purpose. Now, we can freely open and close forms. What remains is the data alone.

```
public class Data
{
    public string Greeting { get; set; }
}
```

`Form2` code:

```
private readonly Data _data;

public Form2(Data data) // Note that now, we pass a Data object, not a Form
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _data = data;
    textBox1.Text = _data.Greeting;
}

private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _data.Greeting = textBox1.Text; // Stores back text box edits to the Data object.
}
```

`Form1` code:

```
private readonly Data _data = new Data();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _data.Greeting = "Hello";
    var frm2 = new Form2(_data);
    frm2.Show();
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm2 = new Form2(_data);
    frm2.Show();
}
```